# How can i access a required field validator in javascript which is set Enabled="false" in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

How can i access a required field validator in javascript which is set Enabled="false" in aspx page?
On selection of another dropdown this requiredfieldvalidator should be enabled.

Comment: @Eonasdan, validator controls are definitely rendered if `Enabled="false"` and are accessible via JS. I use the technique regularly for complex form building

Comment: @freefaller thanks. I wasn't sure. I was just trying to help the OP think about that kind of thing. I guess I was thinking about `visible`

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript function, you need something like...

```
document.getElementById("<%=valMyValidator.ClientId%>").enabled = true;
```